# What means the "->" in node.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to learn about the [connect-livereload](http://jaketrent.com/post/livereload-for-nodejs/) module and after installing it, is written this :

Next, import:

```
app.configure 'development', ->
  app.use require('connect-livereload') 35729
```

is that "**->**" sign just a typo or what it stands for ? i would suppose it's just a typo if these two lines weren't chained with just a comma so that's why i ask.

Comment: This is [tag:coffescript], not javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is nothing node specific. That code is writting in coffeescript

in javascript that is the same as

```
app.configure('development', function() {
  return app.use(require('connect-livereload')(35729));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`->` is an operator used in `CoffeScript`.

> Functions are defined by an optional list of parameters in parentheses, an arrow, and the function body.

[reference at coffescript.com](http://coffeescript.org/#literals)

Answer (score 1):

That's not JavaScript, it's [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). It's a function. The JavaScript translation is:

```
app.configure('development', function() {
    return app.use(require('connect-livereload'), 36729);
});
```